# I'm trying to write a JavaScript script using handlebars to check the count of each product, if its at least 1 or more place a green circle on it

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I'm trying to write a JavaScript script using handlebars to check the count of each product, if its at least 1 or more place a green circle on it. we have web page for our company and we have the product list, now i tried multiple logic's and i think the problem is with placing the script. I'm trying to add a block of code to the product-view.html file that is provided below.

```
{{#each products}}
{{#gt units 1}}
<div style="width: 60px; height: 60px; background-color: green; border-radius: 60%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;">
In Stock
</div>
{{/gt}}

{{/each}}



{{inject 'outOfStockDefaultMessage' (lang 'products.out_of_stock_default_message')}}

<div class="productView"
data-event-type="product"
data-entity-id="{{product.id}}"
data-name="{{product.title}}"
data-product-category="
{{#each product.category}}
    {{#if @last}}{{this}}{{else}}{{this}}, {{/if}}
{{/each}}"
data-product-brand="{{product.brand.name}}"
data-product-price="
{{#or customer (unless settings.hide_price_from_guests)}}
    {{#if product.price.with_tax}}
        {{product.price.with_tax.value}}
    {{else}}
        {{product.price.without_tax.value}}
    {{/if}}



{{else}}
    {{lang 'common.login_for_pricing'}}
{{/or}}"
data-product-variant="single-product-option">

{{#each product.reviews.messages}}
    {{#if error}}
        {{> components/common/alert/alert-error error}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if success}}
        {{> components/common/alert/alert-success success}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}



<section class="productView-images" data-image-gallery>
    {{!--
        Note that these image sizes are coupled to image sizes used in /assets/js/theme/common/product-details.js
        for variant/rule image replacement
    --}}
    {{#if product.images.length '>' 1 }}
    {{> components/carousel-content-announcement}}


    {{/if}}
    <figure class="productView-image"
            data-image-gallery-main
            {{#if product.main_image}}
            data-zoom-image="{{getImageSrcset product.main_image (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product) 1x=theme_settings.zoom_size }}"
            {{/if}}
            >
        <div class="productView-img-container">
            {{!-- Remove the surrounding a-element if there is no main image. --}}
            {{#if product.main_image}}
                <a href="{{getImageSrcset product.main_image (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product) 1x=theme_settings.zoom_size}}"
                    target="_blank">


                

            {{/if}}
            {{> components/common/responsive-img
                image=product.main_image
                class="productView-image--default"
                fallback_size=theme_settings.product_size
                lazyload=theme_settings.lazyload_mode
                default_image=theme_settings.default_image_product
                otherAttributes="data-main-image"
            }}
            {{!-- Remove the surrounding a-element if there is no main image. --}}
            {{#if product.main_image}}
                </a>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </figure>
    <ul class="productView-thumbnails"{{#gt product.images.length 5}} data-slick='{
            "infinite": false,
            "mobileFirst": true,
            "dots": false,
            "accessibility": false,
            "slidesToShow": 5,
            "slidesToScroll": 5
        }'{{/gt}}>

        {{#each product.images}}
            <li class="productView-thumbnail">
                <a
                    class="productView-thumbnail-link"
                    href="{{getImageSrcset this (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_product) 1x=../theme_settings.zoom_size}}"
                    data-image-gallery-item
                    data-image-gallery-new-image-url="{{getImageSrcset this (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_product) 1x=../theme_settings.product_size}}"
                    data-image-gallery-new-image-srcset="{{getImageSrcset this use_default_sizes=true}}"
                    data-image-gallery-zoom-image-url="{{getImageSrcset this (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_product) 1x=../theme_settings.zoom_size}}"
                >


                {{> components/common/responsive-img
                    image=this
                    fallback_size=../theme_settings.productview_thumb_size
                    lazyload=../theme_settings.lazyload_mode
                }}
                </a>
            </li>


        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</section>

<section class="productView-details product-data">
    <div class="productView-product">
        <h1 class="productView-title">{{product.title}}</h1>
        {{#if product.brand}}
            <h2 class="productView-brand">
                <a href="{{product.brand.url}}"><span>{{product.brand.name}}</span></a>
            </h2>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if product.call_for_price}}
            <p class="productView-price">
                <span>{{product.call_for_price}}</span>
            </p>
        {{/if}}
        <div class="productView-price">
            

            {{#or customer (unless settings.hide_price_from_guests)}}
                {{> components/products/price price=product.price}}
            {{else}}
                {{> components/common/login-for-pricing}}
            {{/or}}
        </div>
        {{{region name="product_below_price"}}}
        <div class="productView-rating">
            {{#if settings.show_product_rating}}
                {{> components/products/ratings rating=product.rating}}
                {{#if product.num_reviews '>' 0}}
                    <a href="{{product.url}}{{#if is_ajax}}#product-reviews{{/if}}" id="productReview_link">
                        {{lang 'products.reviews.link_to_review' total=product.num_reviews}}
                    </a>
                {{else}}
                    <span>{{lang 'products.reviews.link_to_review' total=product.num_reviews}}</span>
                {{/if}}
            {{/if}}
            {{#if settings.show_product_reviews}}
                <a href="{{product.url}}{{#if is_ajax}}#write_review{{/if}}"
                   class="productView-reviewLink productView-reviewLink--new"
                   {{#unless is_ajax}}data-reveal-id="modal-review-form"{{/unless}}
                   role="button"
                >
                   {{lang 'products.reviews.new'}}
                </a>
                {{#unless is_ajax}}
                    {{> components/products/modals/writeReview}}
                {{/unless}}
            {{/if}}
        </div>
        {{product.detail_messages}}
        <dl class="productView-info">
            <dt class="productView-info-name sku-label"{{#unless product.sku}} style="display: none;"{{/unless}}>{{lang 'products.sku'}}</dt>
            <dd class="productView-info-value" data-product-sku>{{product.sku}}</dd>
            <dt class="productView-info-name upc-label"{{#unless product.upc}} style="display: none;"{{/unless}}>{{lang 'products.upc'}}</dt>
            <dd class="productView-info-value" data-product-upc>{{product.upc}}</dd>
            {{#if product.condition}}
                <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.condition'}}</dt>
                <dd class="productView-info-value">{{product.condition}}</dd>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if product.availability}}
                <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.availability'}}</dt>
                <dd class="productView-info-value">{{product.availability}}</dd>

            {{/if}}
            {{#all product.weight theme_settings.show_product_weight}}
                <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.weight'}}</dt>
                <dd class="productView-info-value" data-product-weight>{{product.weight}}</dd>
            {{/all}}
            {{#all product.width product.height product.depth theme_settings.show_product_dimensions}}
                <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.width'}}</dt>
                <dd class="productView-info-value" data-product-width>
                    {{product.width}}
                    {{#if settings.measurements.length '==' 'Centimeters'}}
                    ({{lang 'products.measurement.metric'}})
                    {{else}}
                    ({{lang 'products.measurement.imperial'}})
                    {{/if}}
                </dd>
                <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.height'}}</dt>
                <dd class="productView-info-value" data-product-height>
                    {{product.height}}
                    {{#if settings.measurements.length '==' 'Centimeters'}}
                    ({{lang 'products.measurement.metric'}})
                    {{else}}
                    ({{lang 'products.measurement.imperial'}})
                    {{/if}}
                </dd>
                <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.depth'}}</dt>
                <dd class="productView-info-value" data-product-depth>
                    {{product.depth}}
                    {{#if settings.measurements.length '==' 'Centimeters'}}
                    ({{lang 'products.measurement.metric'}})
                    {{else}}
                    ({{lang 'products.measurement.imperial'}})
                    {{/if}}
                </dd>
            {{/all}}
            {{#if product.min_purchase_quantity}}
                <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.min_purchase_quantity'}}</dt>
                <dd class="productView-info-value">{{lang 'products.purchase_units' quantity=product.min_purchase_quantity}}</dd>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if product.max_purchase_quantity}}
                <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.max_purchase_quantity'}}</dt>
                <dd class="productView-info-value">{{lang 'products.purchase_units' quantity=product.max_purchase_quantity}}</dd>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if product.gift_wrapping_available}}
                <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.gift_wrapping'}}</dt>
                <dd class="productView-info-value">{{lang 'products.gift_wrapping_available'}}</dd>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if product.shipping}}
                {{#if product.shipping.calculated}}
                    <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.shipping'}}</dt>
                    <dd class="productView-info-value">{{lang 'products.shipping_calculated'}}</dd>
                {{else}}
                    {{#if product.shipping.price.value '===' 0}}
                        <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.shipping'}}</dt>
                        <dd class="productView-info-value">{{lang 'products.shipping_free'}}</dd>
                    {{else}}
                        <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.shipping'}}</dt>
                        <dd class="productView-info-value">{{lang 'products.shipping_fixed' amount=product.shipping.price.formatted}}</dd>
                    {{/if}}
                {{/if}}
            {{/if}}

            {{#if settings.bulk_discount_enabled}}
                <div class="productView-info-bulkPricing">
                    {{> components/products/bulk-discount-rates bulk_discount_rates=product.bulk_discount_rates}}
                </div>
            {{/if}}

            {{#if theme_settings.show_custom_fields_tabs '!==' true}}
                {{> components/products/custom-fields }}
            {{/if}}
        </dl>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="productView-details product-options">
    <div class="productView-options">
        {{#if product.release_date }}
            <p>{{product.release_date}}</p>
        {{/if}}
        <form class="form" method="post" action="{{product.cart_url}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"
              data-cart-item-add>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{product.id}}"/>
            {{#if product.cart_order_source}}
                <input type="hidden" name="cart_order_source" value="{{product.cart_order_source}}"/>
            {{/if}}
            <div data-product-option-change style="display:none;">
                {{inject 'showSwatchNames' theme_settings.show_product_swatch_names}}
                {{#each product.options}}
                    {{{dynamicComponent 'components/products/options'}}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-field form-field--stock{{#unless product.stock_level}} u-hiddenVisually{{/unless}}">
                <label class="form-label form-label--alternate">
                    {{lang 'products.current_stock'}}
                    <span data-product-stock>{{product.stock_level}}</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            {{> components/products/add-to-cart with_wallet_buttons=true}}
            {{#if product.out_of_stock}}
                {{#if product.out_of_stock_message}}
                    {{> components/common/alert/alert-error product.out_of_stock_message}}
                {{else}}
                    {{> components/common/alert/alert-error (lang 'products.sold_out')}}
                {{/if}}
            {{/if}}
        </form>

        {{#if settings.show_wishlist}}
            {{> components/common/wishlist-dropdown}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
    {{> components/common/share url=product.url}}
</section>

<article class="productView-description">
    {{#if theme_settings.show_product_details_tabs}}
        {{> components/products/description-tabs}}
    {{else}}
        {{> components/products/description}}
    {{/if}}
</article>
```

```
<div id="previewModal" class="modal modal--large" data-reveal>
{{> components/common/modal/modal-close-btn }}
<div class="modal-content"></div>
<div class="loadingOverlay"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "I think the problem is with placing the script" ?

Comment: I think the problem is where should i put this block of code within the product-view file, but I'm not sure.                                                                                          
{{#each products}}
{{#gt units 1}}
<div style="width: 60px; height: 60px; background-color: green; border-radius: 60%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;">
In Stock
</div>
{{/gt}}

{{/each}}
unless if it the logic that is wrong.

Comment: I don't think you have narrowed down the information you are providing in order for someone to reasonably answer your question.

Comment: The product-view.html file is specifically for the PDP (product display page). There is no "products" object to reference here.

You mention a "list," do you mean the category page? If so, you probably want to be editing the category.html or card.html files.

Comment: {{#unless out_of_stock_message}}
    
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: rgb(39, 185, 39); border-radius: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;">
        In Stock
      </div>

    {{/unless}}                                                                                                                   so i got this block of code in the card.html. and it's displaying the green circle on every page of the my website, except for the product page. any suggestions?